# Chrome Extension: How do I poll RSS Feeds to see if there is new content and display that as a number on the extension icon

Tags: google-chrome, rss, notifications, google-chrome-extension

I wonder if you could help a little.

I want to have a simple Extension, that shows the number of new items in a RSS feed since the extension was clicked.

It would poll every 2-3 mins for example and if the RSS feed is updated it should display a count of how many new items there are. I assume it has to set the  setBadgeText field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to implement a couple of things.

A [background_page](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) that will contain all of your code and periodically poll the RSS feed.

Within the backround_page you will have to use [XHR](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) to request the feed.

After you get the feed parse it and compare with a list of previous posts in localStorage. If there are new ones use [chrome.browserAction.setBadgetText()](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText) to update the displayed count.

Once a user clicks on the browserAction button you will likely want to open a new tab to the website with [chrome.tabs.create()](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) and clear the shown new count.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText) API.

Something like:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: '5' });
```